# Replacing two distinct values inside a formulas at once using Control + H in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have multiple formulas on different pages of the spreadsheet like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(
O2:O="","",
O2:O="VOID","",
L2:L=1,IF(P2:P>Q2:Q,"GREEN","RED"),
L2:L="X",IF(P2:P=Q2:Q,"GREEN","RED"),
L2:L=2,IF(P2:P<Q2:Q,"GREEN","RED"),
J2:J="More than 2.5 goals",IF(P2:P+Q2:Q>2.5,"GREEN","RED")))
```

Is there a way to use `Control + H` to change all `GREEN` to `RED` and all `RED` to `GREEN` at once?

Something like I could do like what would happen if I used `SUBSTITUTE` on a string:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RANGE,"GREEN","RED"),"RED","GREEN")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical problem with what you are suggesting. If you were to actually try your SUBSTITUTE formula, you would see that *everything* would wind up `GREEN` in the end, because you would have changed all `GREEN` to `RED` *first* (which would have left *everything* `RED`) and then changed all `RED` (i.e., everything) back to `GREEN`.

You can use Find/Replace. But you'll need to do it in three steps:

1.) Change `GREEN` to, say, `HOLD`.

2.) Change `RED` to `GREEN`.

3.) Change `HOLD` to `RED`.

Since the Find/Replace dialog window stays open, you should be able to do this for an entire spreadsheet in about 15 seconds.